# Use partially typed library

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, pixi.js

I'm trying to use a library (PixiJS) which has an out of date typings definition from '@types/pixi.js'.  How do I use the existing types and also types that aren't yet defined?  I'm trying to do the following:

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';  // use PIXI types (PIXI.Renderer, PIXI.stage, etc)
declare var PIXI.Application: any;  // untyped PIXI.Application
```

In VSCode I get the following error:

```
[ts] Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'PIXI'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation):

```
import * as PIXI from "pixi.js";

declare module "pixi.js" {
    class Application {}
}

const app = new PIXI.Application();
```

I just added the `Application` as a class without any methods as I don't really know this library, but using this method you can add whatever you need.

---

#### Edit

That's not an implementation, notice the `declare` keyword.
You are adding to the existing module declaration, the class there is just a declaration, if you want to add methods to it for example you only add the signatures.
For example if that class has a `echo` method then it will look like this:

```
declare module "pixi.js" {
    class Application {
        echo(value: string): string;
    }
}
```

For more info check the provided link.

Comment: PIXI.Application already exists in the javascript so I don't need an implementation, the types library is just missing the typing.

Comment: See my revised answer